# How can I affect color of a water droplet shot?

Tags: lighting, macro, water

Experimenting with water droplets today. Pretty fun! I'd like to ask how can I improve upon it. First of all a picture of the setup:

[image]

Water is contained within a plastic bag that is taped to a tall-ish black lamp. Water drops into a big bowl that is covered with black plastic because the bowl itself is white. Flash is pointed towards a styrofoam background that is all white. Kinda ghetto home setup but it mostly works :) Now a sample of the results, SOOC:

[image]

Although the results actually turned out quite pleasing, my first expectation was for the color to follow the background, that is I was expecting it to be all or mostly white. However this is not the case, as there is some black there. How do I fix this if I want the color of the shot to be mostly white?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the shot to be white, don't put a black bin bag in the bowl. If you want to add a touch of colour, try putting some coloured gels (or any coloured transparent plastic) over the flash. I'd try it without the diffuser as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems your correct about the black bag. I added the bag because I wanted the color to come from only the background that is lit by the flash, as I'd want to change the background with different colors. I thought the black plastic would help to ensure that the only color reflected onto the water is whatever the flash is pointing at. Is this not true?

Comment: Take a look at this guide for water drop photography: http://www.diyphotography.net/the-comprehensive-water-drop-photography-guide

Comment: If you want it to be purely white, you could always try milk?

Comment: Thanks for the link! thats quite an investment he made.. over 500$! Cool devices though. Regarding the milk, my question is less about the color n more about how to reflect the background color onto the water. replace "white" with blue, red, yellow, etc. im wondering how to reflect whatever my flash is pointing to onto the water.

Comment: Well, you already _are_ reflecting the white card onto the droplet; you can see that the highlights of the drop are white. The best thing to do is experiment with different backgrounds, different colours in the bowl, and different colour gels on the flash and see what the results are for yourself.

Comment: ElendilTheTall has covered the basics I think. The bounce from the backdrop is how I did these: http://www.grumpyjohns.com/2009/psychedelic_water_art/

Comment: Thanks john! I think the snoot can help me remove unwanted reflections. Looking at Elendil's link I think I wanna try moving the lights to behind the water and diffuse it with fabric or something, and also try gels. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nice Image!

I think this is how i would try it in 3d and should work for RealLife images too.

Step1. Creat a semi-transperent white shpere almost like in this picture just bigger.
http://i31.twenga.com/homewares/lampshade/12-spherical-paper-lamp-tp_2959502265558139280b.png

Step2. Cut a hole for the lens.
Step3. If you have more than one flashlight (like Nikon Creative Lighting System) i would place them outside of the of the sphere. The distance of flashlight to shpere will creat sharper or softer reflections.

Step4. add different colour diffusers to your flashlight or lights.

Note. in 3d i would light a scene with a spherical hdri map,

http://www.hdrlightstudio.com/asset/image/section/hdri_light_packs/7.jpg

i think this should creat the proper effect you aim.

Hope that this answer helps you XD

Comment: Thanks! I kinda lost you at "spherical hdri map"... I understand your basic idea :) I don't think I need a full light sphere/box to do it tho. It would limit my angles too much.

Comment: okies are you on flickr? or something i would like to follow you and see more nice drops :)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I am not on flickr. I occasionally post to deviantart at rabbid83@deviantart.com and I keep a gallery at kevinpw.net. :)