# How to shoot a image refracted through a drop of water?

Tags: water, special-effects

How can I make a photo like this?

[image: spiderman drop example]

Please note that this is just a example (I don`t want a shot of Spiderman).

Comment: see this related question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15416/how-can-i-affect-color-of-a-water-droplet-shot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your cam on a tripod, your picture in the background, make something up for the drops of water (bottle of water with a pinhole at the bottom, for example), and focus on the drops.
This tutorial should get you started nicely: http://www.mcpactions.com/blog/2011/02/09/how-to-shoot-amazing-water-droplet-macro-photographs/